# Customizing Notification email on Elastic Beanstalk Environment Health

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sns

I am trying to customize the default email that is sent when the Elastic Beanstalk environment health changes

Example: 
When the health transitions from Ok to Severe, an email is sent out to the email address(Elastic Beanstalk Environment -> configuration -> notification )

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.sns.html

I would like edit the default subject (add a specific text in the subject line) of the Notification that comes out when the health of the environment transitions.

I am unable to find the best approach to accomplish this, any pointers to customize the email notification will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really customize SNS messages. The typical way to accomplish this is to have SNS trigger a Lambda function instead of sending an email, then the Lambda function can construct the email exactly how you want and send it via SES.

Comment: I did take the approach as you suggested. However, not all kinds of event are reported. Events such as "yellow to green" will be reported, but issues like 'server restarted' will never trigger an SNS. Wonder if there is any way to solve it?

Comment: @ChenLin hey, did you manage to solve this problem?
I also want to have slack messages when new version is deployed, but now it's not possible